# Checking if window of specific application is in minimized state?

Tags: c++, windows, window

Hey guys i am trying to write a program in c++ which can check if an application suppose powerpoint or word is running in minimized form or window is opened...
I am new to this concept of windows programming please help....

I have taken a code from @Max keilland...

```
TCHAR WndCaption[100];
TCHAR NewCaption[] = TEXT("My Window handle is valid");
BOOL res;

GetWindowText(MyHWND,WndCaption,100);
SetWindowText(MyHWND,NewCaption);

// This works correctly.
res = IsWindowVisible(MyHWND);
if(!res) {
   // This always fail
   OpenIcon(MyHWND);
}
```

where should i pass my name of application to check if that is in minimized state or not.....

PS: it also shows MyHWND not found????
Please can you give me an idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`IsIconic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic) function.

The documentation states:

> ```
> BOOL IsIconic(
>   HWND hWnd
> );
> ```
>
> Determines whether the specified window is minimized (iconic).
>
> Return Value
>   Type: Type: `BOOL`
>
> If the window is iconic, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the window is not iconic, the return value is zero.

Comment: thanks for the reply...But how can i use it can you please tell something more it will be of great help...

Comment: You have to pass the handle of the window `hWnd` for which you want to know the status to this function.

Comment: Thanks again...But how can i get the handle of a window???Ps: I am new to this .....Can you please help....

Comment: The code in the question shows that you already have the handle which seems to be: `MyHWND`

Comment: No after running this program it gives MyHWND not found.... If you can help how to get handle of a function.....

Comment: I think it is better you get hold of a good book on windows programming that will give you the basics to do these kind of things.

Comment: @JohnWick1 "*how can i get the handle of a window?*" - look at `FindWindow()` and related functions

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for suggesting... I read about that function got some idea...Can you please suggest changes in my above code if i can do something to make it work... I want to know if an application is in minimized state or not.....I will be of great help,,....PS: this is used in my college project...